# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FGalleryViewController", referenced from:

Tags: iphone

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FGalleryViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Home.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: `cc: question.c line 1 column 1: expected 'question', found no 'effort'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe class named `FGalleryViewController` is not linked with project target. Please check it once.

Comment: Select Project in your Xcode navigator, Select Target and navigate to "Build Phases" tab and expand "Compile Sources" option and check if "FGalleryViewController.m" file is available there or not.

Comment: Hi@BornCoder in my case i already added it to my project But still get the error.